# Chat thread using firebase and Behaviorsuject issue

Tags: firebase, angular, rxjs

I am a newcomer in programming and learning new things,
So I'm using observable, angular2 and firebase to build a chat thread  for one of my project, but I'm facing  some littles issues.

Please find the below code for more information.

```
  loadmessagesForU(currentUser){
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.rootRef.child('users').child(currentUser).child('rooms').on('child_added', snapshot => {
        this.key = snapshot.key()
        this.rootRef.child('messages').child(this.key).on('value', snapshot => {
          const data = snapshot.val()
          const loto = _.toArray(data)
          const last = _.last(loto)
          this.rootRef.child('users').orderByKey().equalTo(last.sender).on('child_added', snapshot => {
            observer.next({sendername: snapshot.val().nom, lastmessage: last.messages})
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

This is how I'm taking each value to build my thread, I need to take this.key, last.message, sender.name etc to build my thread, I can easily take them this way and use them but its works has half, each time I have a new message, it create a new object instead of refreshing just the last message one and its not feeling what I really need, have things more ordered and use model and Behaviorsubject to build my thread.

I had ended up with this code.

```
  loadmessagesForU(currentUser){
    const ThreadObservable = new BehaviorSubject<Thread[]>(null)
      this.rootRef.child('users').child(currentUser).child('rooms').on('child_added', snapshot => {
        this.key = snapshot.key()
        this.rootRef.child('messages').child(this.key).on('value', snapshot => {
          const data = snapshot.val()
          const loto = _.toArray(data)
          const last = _.last(loto)
          this.rootRef.child('users').orderByKey().equalTo(last.sender).on('child_added', snapshot => {
            MessagesObservable.next({sendername: snapshot.val().nom, lastmessage: last.messages})
          })
        })
      })
      return ThreadObservable
  }
```

So how can I group each value not taken at the same level, have last message refreshing and not create new object and return it into my model.